# Download file Error 2 , FileTransferError.INVALID_URL_ERR

Tags: javascript, xcode, cordova, http-response-codes

I'm using Phonegap[cordova 1.7.0] to download a file using Xcode[ios5]. 
This is the code I'm using to download the file:

```
   function downloadfile(){
   var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
   console.log('the type of root is:');
   fileTransfer.download(
                  "http://184.172.195.202:90/ElmNoor/Documents/1.txt",
                  persistent_root.fullPath,
                  function(entry) {
                  alert("I'm Downloading");
                  console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
                  },
                  function(error) {
                  alert("I'm not downloading");
                  console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                  console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                  console.log("upload error code " + error.code);
                  }
                  );}
```

But I get **Error code 2** & I don't know can I solve it?

This is my log:

```
     HelloPhoneGap[933:13403] File Transfer Finished with response code 200
     HelloPhoneGap[933:13403] [INFO] download error source http://184.172.195.202:90/ElmNoor/Documents/1.txt
     HelloPhoneGap[933:13403] [INFO] download error target /Users/weekend/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/A7883F4B-7678-    4424-A93A-77747297A11E/Documents
     HelloPhoneGap[933:13403] [INFO] upload error code 2
```

I changed the url, but it gave the same error. Do you know what's wrong ?

**PS: I knew the problem & added the answer below =)**

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anyone is facing the same problem, here is the answer:

To download a file you shouldn't just add the path of the folder that it'll be downloaded in, you should also add the path of the file itself.

So if you are downloading a jpg image to "Documents", file path should be: "Document"+".jpg".

here is the code after modification:

```
   function DownloadFile(){
   var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
   var url ="http://www.ranafrog.org.au/f006.jpg";
   var folderpath=persistent_root.fullPath+"frog.jpg"; //The path is added here.
   var onSuccess= function(entry){
   console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
};

var onError=function(error) {
    console.log("download error source " + error.source);
    console.log("download error target " + error.target);
    console.log("upload error code " + error.code);
};

fileTransfer.download(url,folderpath,onSuccess,onError);
}
```

I don't not sure whether what I'm saying is 100% correct or not, but that's what worked for me ,,, so hope it helps =)

Comment: HUGE help. Had exactly the same error, and the docs don't help at all. All they give you is "Assumes variable url contains a valid URI to a file on a server and filePath is a valid path on the device". Thank you.

Comment: So to use the var names from the documentation:  fileSystem.root.fullPath + '/frog.jpg';  // forward slash is missing

Comment: 10 years later.  However I added the file name to the full path and am still getting FileError 2....and, the file "myFile.jpg" that is being saved as `myFile.jpg.myFile.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i made a mistake, The error code 2 should be INVALID_URL_ERR； 
So, you can try a normal url(not 90 port but 80 port) for test,

"http://184.172.195.202/ElmNoor/Documents/1.txt",
 persistent_root.fullPath + "/" + "1.txt",  //attention, must add

it should can download normal.

Answer (score 0):

What this error says is - you have a `FileTransferError.INVALID_URL_ERR` error. This means that the path at which you are trying to save your downloaded file is not correct.

Cross-check your path by outputting it to the `console`.

PS: You can verify that the URL from which you are downloading is correct by trying it out in the normal browser.